# How to redirect a user to login page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, redirect

My default page is home page but i want to redirect a user to login page is he is not logged in. i tried the following in partial view  but failed

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div>Welcone</div>
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing this in view..do checking stuff in controller side and redirect from there using `return RedirectToAction(...`.

Comment: thanks for the guidance but mvc by default provides this functionality i mean which one is the best practice more over if i add my own layout to the login.cshtml it does not call post function why is it so?

Comment: There should be minimum or no code inside view that is the best practice.

Comment: Sounds good this really make sense..  Thanks Kartikeya Khola.. :)

Comment: Use `[Authorize]` attribute in your controller.

Comment: Thanks SeM.. which approach would you suggest is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kartikeya Khosla answer worked for me. I did it in this way

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
```